# Binary least squares classification labeling {0,1} vs {1,-1)

Tags: classification, linear, labeling

I am trying to find the best possible line which discriminates my data with least squares. I have 2 points, $\pmb{x}_0=\{1,2\}$ which belongs to the class $y=+1$ and $\pmb{x}_1=\{2,1\}$ which belongs to the class $y=-1$.

I use the formula
$\pmb{\theta}=(\pmb{X}^T\pmb{X})^{-1} \pmb{X}^Ty$.

With the classes $\{-1,+1\}$, the line is $x1-x2=0$ which is normal.

[image]

If I change the classes to $\{0,+1\}$, the line is $1-x1+x2=0$ which does not seem normal.

[image]

Any ideas why the least squares formula does not work with different labeling?

Comment: You must have made an error, because this change of class labels is merely a linear change of units and so the solution must be identical (albeit with a different formula).  In fact, none of these graphics is consistent with the data you report, which seem to be the four ordered pairs $(1,1),(2,1),(2,-1),(1,-1)$ representing the $(x,y)$ values.  Possibly they are the two $(x_0,x_1,y)$ triples $(1,2,1), (2,1,-1),$ but then you would be attempting to construct a *plane* through two points, and again none of your graphics make sense.  Could you explain how these graphics are related to your data?

Comment: Hello @whuber. There are 2 data points. Every point has 2 dimensions and a label. For the first data point the 2 dimensions have values {1,2} and the label is the red colour which I write it down as y= -1. The other data point {2,1} has label the colour blue, which I write it as y = +1. So there are the same 2 data points in every plot.